# cant run eclipse on mac 32bit

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

im trying to install eclipse on my mac (32bit). There is a pop saying that i need to use the latest jdk and from java.com the jdk i need is not available to 32bit running osx. The jdk they have for mac is 64bit version only. Any suggestion on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that JDK 1.7 is only available for 64bit OS X versions. If you are asked for JDK 1.7 you are probably trying to install Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). What you can do is install Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). This works with JDK 1.6. Apple has its own version of JDK, and its probaby installed by default. If not i guess you can use Software Update to get it.

Comment: oh i see. i thought theres a way to use the latest eclipse software. alright then ill just stick the eclipse 4.3 thanks